# Writing GML causes XML encoding error?

Tags: shapefile, geotools, gml

I am using `org.geotools` version `2.7.0` and I am trying to get some shapefiles to `GML 3.1.1`. Sadly I got an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Encode failed for _Feature. Cause: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
at org.geotools.xml.impl.ElementEncodeExecutor.visit(ElementEncodeExecutor.java:132)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:215)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:181)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingVisitorDispatch.walk(BindingVisitorDispatch.java:44)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.ElementEncoder.encode(ElementEncoder.java:83)
at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:1100)
at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:836)
at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:564)
```

Maybe it's a space or an accented char (shape's attributes are full of accented chars) but I am very new to geotools and GIS, this error is completely blocking me. I can't find a way to specify a charset to read data from shape (by set up `DataStore`) or to write data into GML file (by set up `Encoder`). What am I missing?

---

I am trying to remove not allowed symbols from attributes and element names by using

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (!s.substring(0, 1).matches("[a-zA-Z_]"))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
sb.append(s.substring(0, 1));
for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.substring(i, i + 1).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]")) {
    sb.append(s.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

to sanitize shape feature attribute's values. Now attributes looks good but I am still getting the same exception.

I am new to GIS and `org.geotools`.

Comment: Current GeoTools release is 15.1 - so you might want to try a newer version

Comment: List your attributes. Attribute names in GML are of type NCName which means that everything is not acceptable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631396/what-is-an-xsncname-type-and-when-should-it-be-used.

Comment: @iant Hello, I can't upgrade right now. Do you think it's an already solved issue?

Comment: @Franz - who knows that's 8 full releases old, you could check the release notes for each one, start at https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/geotools-270-released.html  and work forward

Comment: @iant maybe the issue happens when shapefile has spaces in its name?

Comment: @Franz - we need an example shapefile, a list of it's attributes and your code to start debugging this

Comment: @iant sorry I can't share. Exception occurs with 15.1 version too. I'm looking for a way to sanitize shape before encoding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it. I have to check for every `SimpleFeatureTypeImpl` attribute who is an instance of `AttributeDescriptorImpl`. I check if it's name's local part and id are valid NCNames values. I replaced every non NCName entry with a NCName valid one. To check if a String is a NCName one I used `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.internal.DataValue.XMLChar.isValidNCName()`. This prevents error due to spaces in shapefile's name.